# Xeokit-sdk: Transfrom Normal vector to squere pointer camera oriented

Tags: javascript, 3d

Used xeokit-sdk for display models.

Xeokit-sdk has plugin for distance measurements, his display points and line on css use matrixs, etc, but i want to change the pointer from circle to to square when hover surface like on screenshots(not from xeokit).

When pick/hover some surface can get normalVector, point coordinates etc.
It is possible to display square pointer also on css. Pointer must be paraller surface and consider camera position.

[image]

[image]

I tried to get euler angles but it still wrong result because camera position not used and pointer always have the same rotation angles.